# Can you mask URLs usign the Classroom Share API

Tags: google-classroom

When using the Classroom Share API, is it possible to "automatically" mask the URLs so the end user never sees the actual URL?

Comment: Do you mean 'data-url'? The URL that is shared to Classroom is determined by the button's data-url attribute. This attribute explicitly defines the target URL to share and must be set in order to render the share button. https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/sharebutton#share_tag_attributes

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you have an example of another site doing the sort of URL masking you'd like to do via the Share API? As @d.datul1990 notes, you can use the [`data-url`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/sharebutton#share_tag_attributes) attribute to point to whatever you want, but the user will see the final URL eventually.

Comment: Could you use a short URL to "mask" it?  (This is why short URLs are dangerous...)